# Asp.net Core - Generic Repository Pattern - Search with TrimStart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I'm using generic repository pattern like below.

I have been assigned to do a task like this

Order_Confirmation Table like below

[image]

if the user search order normally he enters a full OrderID like this - **000008666000**
then in the normal procedure, I used **FindList** and get the result

but now the wants to search like this - **8666000**
they want to search it without leading zeros in OrderID.

but in the repository pattern, I cannot write it with the trimming option. I'm getting an error

```
 var items = _bookingRepository.FindList(s => s.OrderID.TrimStart('0') == value).ToList();
```

Error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Order_Confirmation>()
> .Where(j => j.OrderID.TrimStart(0) == __value_0)'
> could not be translated. Additional information:
> Translation of method 'string.TrimStart'
> failed. If this method can be mapped
> to your custom function,
> see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413
> for more information. Either rewrite
> the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'.
> See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

Is there a way to fix this issue?
I know this will cost lots of performance issues. but this is the requirment.
Generic repository pattern

[image]

Implementations like this

[image]

Comment: Enjoy: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22924

Comment: @ZhiLv I ll update this with my solution

Comment: @TDM, Glad to hear you have found the solution, you can accept it as an answer, and hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue. Have an enjoyable day!

Comment: @Zhi Lv Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abled to fix this issue by using the stored procedure with my exact trim requirment.

Because as @Svyatoslav Danyliv mentioned in the repository pattern, it's not possible.
the best option would be to call the stored procedure and get relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `EndsWith()` or `Contains()` method to filter the data:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var value = "8666000";
    var result = _repository.FindList(s => s.OrderID.EndsWith(value)).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

Besides, you can also get all records first, then before using the `TrimStart()` method, call the `ToList()` method first, code like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var value = "8666000";
    var result = _repository.GetAll().ToList().Where(s=>s.OrderID.TrimStart('0')==value).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

The result like this:

[image]